# Why ”Type Bound mismatch: The type ? extends T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Enum<E>> of the type Enum<E>“？

Tags: java, hadoop, generics

I am trying to read the hadoop 1.0.0 source code in eclipse. I downloaded the source code first and then use `ant eclipse` to build the project. After that, I successfully created the project in eclipse. But there is an error `Type Bound mismatch: The type ? extends T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Enum<E>> of the type Enum<E>` on the line 396 of `Gridmix.java`. The error code:

```
private <T> String getEnumValues(Enum<? extends T>[] e) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String sep = "";
  for (Enum<? extends T> v : e) {
    sb.append(sep);
    sb.append(v.name());
    sep = "|";
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: do you know what version of Java you are building with? make sure it is compatible

Comment: I am using jdk 1.8 now. I will try jdk 1.6.

Comment: Why Hadoop 1.x? Have you compared that class to Hadoop 3?

Comment: I have solved the problem now. Thanks to Patrick Parker. If I use jdk 1.6 and eclipse Kepler, there will be no errors.

Comment: I just want to learn the source codes of Hadoop but the newest version is too complex. so I choose the older version.

Comment: @windkl good you can post what you discovered as the answer. I am glad my suggestion proved helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enum itself is generic (in pure Java) with restriction on the parameter `T` so:

```
`Enum<T extends <Enum<T>>`
```

You don't have any restriction on T in your code, so compiler complains, because You may end up with `T = Object`, but `Enum` cannot accept `Object` as `T`.

So you have to restrict `T` in your code as well:

```
private <T extends Enum<T>> String getEnumValues(Enum<? extends T>[] e) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String sep = "";
    for (Enum<? extends T> v : e) {
        sb.append(sep);
        sb.append(v.name());
        sep = "|";
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

In fact in this case the wildcard wouldn't make sense, because you cannot extend `T` (because you cannot extend any specific `enum`). But that should already compile. If not, drop the wildcard.

I see, it's not your code. So probably some older Java didn't check this properly.